# trying to remove a <li> from a todo list with jquery

Tags: jquery

so im making a Todo list and i have a button that remove the list by id.
im trying to remove the actual list from the page too

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#create-list > button').click(function(){
        let toAdd = $('#create-list > div > input[type="text"]').val();
        $('ol').append('<li>' + toAdd + '</li>');
    });   
});
```

this is how i create a list. could anyone help me how to remove the list from the page?

Comment: See [jQuery.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) in the docs. You do not need to use id to select an element, there are other options, like finding a parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood well, but here is an example how you can add elements in your list with a button to empty that list.

```js
  $(document).ready(
    function() {
      $('#add').click(function() {
          let $input = $('#create-list > div > input[type="text"]');
          let toAdd = $input.val();

           if ($.trim(toAdd)) {
               $('ol').append('<li>' + toAdd + '</li>');
               $input.val('');
           }
      });
      $('#remove').click(function () {
        $('ol').empty();
      });
   }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="create-list">
    <div><input type="text" /></div>
    <ol></ol>
    <button id="add">add</button>
    <button id="remove">remove list</button>
</div>
```